# Get path from open file in Python

Tags: python

If I have an opened file, is there an `os` call to get the complete path as a string?

```
f = open('/Users/Desktop/febROSTER2012.xls')
```

From `f`, how would I get `"/Users/Desktop/febROSTER2012.xls"` ?

Comment: I think this answer is better `os.path.realpath(f.name)` credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867035/1601580

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The key here is the `name` attribute of the `f` object representing the opened file. You get it like that:

```
>>> f = open('/Users/Desktop/febROSTER2012.xls')
>>> f.name
'/Users/Desktop/febROSTER2012.xls'
```

Does it help?

Comment: For files created by: `tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w', prefix='xxx', suffix='.txt')` doesn't work!

Comment: @Victor: Please read the documentation of `tempfile` module, especially for [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), just below the documentation for `tempfile.TemporaryFile` you mentioned. This is specific case for temporary file and, as seen in the docs, there is already existing solution. `tempfile.TemporaryFile` is not meant to be used in case you want to read the name.

Comment: If you create a file using open('foo.txt', 'w') and then do f.name, it only provides you with the output foo.txt

Comment: Zans gives a solution that works for relative paths, too. See his answer below.

Comment: There is tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile in case you need the name.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use a relative path like `f = open('some/relative/path')`, and then change the working directory like `os.chdir('somewhere/esle')`, then `f.name` will not update accordingly, and will not make sense in your current working directory.

Comment: beware that `f.name` does not change when renaming the file, while the file handler will still point to the file now located under a different name. (at least in my distribution of gnu/linux this is the case). So, strictly speaking, `f.name` does not necessarily return the current file name

Comment: why is your answer better than `os.path.realpath(f.name)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867035/1601580?

Comment: name returns back exactly what you passed in to open.  so it's horrible if you really need the full path

Answer (score 157):

I had the exact same issue. If you are using a relative path os.path.dirname(path) will only return the relative path. **os.path.realpath** does the trick:

```
>>> import os
>>> f = open('file.txt')
>>> os.path.realpath(f.name)
```

Comment: This is actually the real answer.

Comment: This only works if the relative file path is still the correct file path.  If I specify the filename as 'text.txt' from directory '~/Documents/' and then change directories to '~/', `os.path.realpath` will return '~/text.txt' instead of '~/Documents/text.txt'.

Comment: I noticed a problem with realpath.  It doesn't correct the case of the files alpha characters but rather keeps the case used in the open statement.  I had hoped it would return the file name as it actually exists on the file system. (This is Windows, of course)

Comment: beware that `f.name` does not change when renaming the file, while the file handler will still point to the file now located under a different name. (at least in my distribution of gnu/linux this is the case). So, strictly speaking, `f.name` does not necessarily return the current file name

Comment: Another issue is that `name` might be something like `<stdin>`.

Answer (score 17):

And if you just want to get the directory name and no need for the filename coming with it, then you can do that in the following conventional way using `os` Python module.

```
>>> import os
>>> f = open('/Users/Desktop/febROSTER2012.xls')
>>> os.path.dirname(f.name)
>>> '/Users/Desktop/'
```

This way you can get hold of the directory structure.

Comment: This returns an empty string if you use `f = open('febROSTER2012.xls')`. How can you get to the full path?

Answer (score 8):

You can get it like this also.

```
filepath = os.path.abspath(f.name)
```

Comment: Which would append it to the current working directory, not the directory where it actually resides.