# Open(Filename, mode) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where to get the File name from?

```
file= open("C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ll\file3.txt", "r")
```

python shows me that there is a syntax error,is it the file name?

Comment: Because a backslash is an escape character...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path from open file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542435/get-path-from-open-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a raw string literal

```
r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ll\file3.txt"
```

or escape your backslashes

```
"C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ll\\file3.txt"
```