# I want to play selected mp3 files in my folder but it doesn't work

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mp3

I get

> ```
> File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject9/main.py", line 26, in play
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
> pygame.error: Couldn't open 'D:/gui/audio/<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/gui/audio/Metallica - The_Unforgiven.mp3' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>.m
> ```

I don't know what to do

Here's the code:

```py
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir='D:/gui/audio', title='Choose a song', filetypes=(('mp3 Files.', '*.mp3'), ))

    # Add songs to list box
    song_box.insert(END, song)
```

```py
# Play selected song
def play():
    song = song_box.get(ACTIVE)
    song = f'D:/gui/audio/{song}.mp3'

    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

Comment: This line `song = f'D:/gui/audio/{song}.mp3'` assumes that `song` is a string. It is not a string, it's a file.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to [`pygame.mixer.music.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) must be the filename of the song and not a file object. Get the name from the file object (see [Get path from open file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542435/get-path-from-open-file-in-python)) to load the music:

<s>`pygame.mixer.music.load(song)`</s>

```py
pygame.mixer.music.load(song.name)
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import tkinter.filedialog

song = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes = (('mp3 Files.', '*.mp3'), ))

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(song.name)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.poll()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```