# python: unexpected output printing variable value

Tags: python, variables

folks,

I'm trying to print a variable value, in this case it should be the command line argument given using Python 3.8.5.

--> code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# import sys to open the file as command line argument
import sys
import pathlib

# open input file given in command line argument
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as ipfi:
    print(f"{ipfi}")
```

--> run:

```
# ./test2.py kern.log.1
```

--> output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='kern.log.1' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

--> expected (desired) output:

```
kern.log.1
```

Tried several print options so far... Any hints on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply `print(sys.argv[1])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542435/get-path-from-open-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print `kern.log.1` use:

```
print(sys.argv[1])
```

you dont need to open the file to do it because you are giving it as an input in the first place.

Edit: if you are trying to print file contents:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```