# How to get the path given file object

Tags: python, pathlib

i have the below posted code, it open a file and write binary contents to it. if the file already exists, the file will be returned.
my question is, given the object `open(pathToFile,'r')` or `outfile`, how can i get the path out of them
i tried the following

```
os.path(tiffFile).name
```

but i receive an error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**code**:

```
def writeBinaryContentsToFile(self,pathToFile, contents):
    # pathToOutputDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), pathToFile)
    logger.debug("pathToFile:{0}".format(pathToFile))
    if not path.exists(pathToFile):
        logger.debug("file will be created")
        with open(pathToFile,"wb") as outfile:
            outfile.write(contents)
        return outfile
    else:
        logger.debug("file already exists")
        return open(pathToFile,'r')
```

Comment: Exactly the same question as [Get path from open file in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542435/get-path-from-open-file-in-python) ... except for the failed attempt. (← although because you don't explain why you think like that there's nothing to explain about it)